# Does google cloud spanner have support of cursor for pagination?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner, google-cloud-spanner-emulator

I am checking on implementing the use of cursors for pagination in the Google Cloud Spanner but am unable to find any example which demonstrates the use of Cursor in Cloud Spanner.

My usecase:
Lets suppose I have a service post-sevice and it is accessing the spanner for the posts with query `SELECT * from posts where time > X and LIMIT 10`, for one spanner call it will fetch 10 posts and when I again do the spanner call with the same query then it should fetch the next 10 posts but not the previous 10 posts.

```
// Initial query
results = executeQueryWithLimitAndCursor(null)

// Store the cursor value for later use
storedCursor = results.cursor

// Display the results to the user

// User requests the next page
nextPageResults = executeQueryWithLimitAndCursor(storedCursor)

// Store the new cursor value for later use
storedCursor = nextPageResults.cursor

// Display the next page results to the user

// Repeat the above steps as needed for more pages
```

---

Got this link but now that much useful as it doesn't seems for spanner: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/samples/datastore-cursor-paging

For code: I didn't even find a single example where this cursor example is given.

Does the spanner go sdk have support of this cursor or not?

Comment: What type of cursor do you mean? `Cursor` is a very generic term for iterating through results that have been returned by a database, and different programming languages have different implementations. Are you looking for a specific type of implementation in a specific language?

Comment: I have requirement of cursor for spanner for the pagination usecase.

Let's suppose I have one service and I want to fetch the spanner database with some condition. So for the first query it will give 10 results and the next cursor value after 10 results. When I execute the query again I will give the cursor value in the request and the spanner will provide me the next 10 results and so on. So it's kinda pagination usecase.

Comment: You can use LIMIT and OFFSET in your query for that: https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#limit_and_offset_clause

Use LIMIT to limit the number of rows to return in a single query.
Use OFFSET to specify how many rows should be skipped.

There are plenty of frameworks that encapsulate this for you. For example:
1. Spring Data JPA supports pagination: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-pagination-sorting
2. Cloud Spanner supports Spring Data JPA

So you could use the combination of those to achieve your goal.

Comment: Thanks, this can be one of the solutions. But I am looking for the optimised solution(I don't know if it is available or not) with the help of cursor. Limit & Offset is not optimal in comparison to the cursor.

Comment: I recommend that this question is closed unless you edit your question and clearly state what you are trying to do and show what you have tried. Using the term `cursor` means many things. You mention pagination - pagination of what? Before posting a question, it is required that you do your own research first so that you can post an on-topic question that can be answered with code correction, facts and/or citations.

Comment: Hey
Sorry @JohnHanley, I updated the question for the use case. For the code, I haven't find any single example in which cursor is used. I am referring to the spanner documentations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/samples/datastore-cursor-paging from datastore, the cursor paging is not supported currently in Cloud Spanner.
As suggested earlier using LIMIT and OFFSET could be a workaround for this.